# How to Copy Content and Add New Record in Telerik Radgrid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, radgrid

Okay, basically I have a master page that only contains a RadGrid. I am using a custom popup WebUserControl form to handle the input for the update/insert controls. When I enter the edit mode I have a button called "Copy & Add New Record". When the user clicks on this button I want to copy 2/3 of the page content, open a new record, and then paste that information in the appropriate textboxes.

I have no problem copying or pasting the information. The problem lies with closing my current edit form and then opening a new record form. I tried closing the form using:

```
Dim temp As RadGrid = Parent.Page.FindControl("rgRT")
temp.MasterTableView.ClearEditItems()
temp.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted = True
```

And then setting the above statement to true to try to open the new record form. However it did not work. The popup edit form was still in the same position, I received no errors, and the only event to occur was an autopostback. I feel like this is something extremely easy but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `Rebind()` call after clearing the insert items. This should put your grid in the defauilt (view mode) and remove the `IsItemInserted = True` call.

Try registering a script to init insert on the client so it goes into edit mode: http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-add-new-row-in-radgrid-clientside-which-should-be-inline-and-stay-in-editmode#hJ-0yiaxakaxzdOf-UXDYw (tip: you would want to use the `Sys.Application.Load` event for your code to execute, earlier calls may cause errors, something like below).

```
string script = "function f(){$find(\"" + RadGrid1.ClientID + "\").get_masterTableView().fireCommand("InitInsert", ""); Sys.Application.remove_load(f);}Sys.Application.add_load(f);";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "key", script, true);
```

then, use the ItemCommand event to set default values: [Telerik RadGrid - How do I set default data on insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406276/telerik-radgrid-how-do-i-set-default-data-on-insert)